# 301 Redirect plugin for wordpress on windows server

Tags: windows, wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301, windows-hosting

I has a wordpress site on azure website, traditionally I has used [Quick Redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) Plugin to redirect some pages to new pages, but this plugin not work on windows cuz is using web.config file instead .htaccess

There are any way to generate 301 redirects for certain page from wordpress when is hosted in windows server, I has searched some plugin to do this but not finded any.

**MORE DETAILS:**

Azure websites use subdomain for azurewebsites.net like myblog.azurewebsites.net, I am configure website url with other masking domain name and work well, but, I want to that when user browse  myblog.azurewebsites.net/category/link redirect to www.mydomain.com/blog/category/link but with 301 redirect in web.config. I am traying several ways, with location and url rewrite but nothing work.

Example of rules used:

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="subdomain\.azurewebsites\.net/([_0-9a-z-/]+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743223/redirect-broken-pages-404-on-wordpress-redirection-301-not-working/34743782#34743782

Comment: What happens now when you try to redirect to that location?

You are able to correctly redirect from azurewebsites -> mydomain correct? But not specifically that link?

Comment: @DaveVoyles I include an example of rule but nothing happen when enter  to a match url

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting your website with [Project Nami](https://projectnami.org/)?

Your wordpress site should still be using .htaccess, although I may be mistaken.

For redirection, I use **[Page Links To](https://github.com/markjaquith/page-links-to)**.

Comment: No, I am using azure cloud

Comment: I understand that you are using Azure, but how did you create the wordpress site?

Are you using clearDB as the db host, or using Project Nami to use a SQL db?

Comment: Try out Page Links To and let me know if that works or redirection

Comment: I has added more detail to my question